# alternate or replacement for recaptcha

Tags: internet-explorer, recaptcha, replace

I have implemented reCaptcha in my site and it is not working in IE vesions. I am currently looking for other captcha services which are similar(**service providers / API calls**) to reCpatcha.

**Could anybody tell me the replacement or alternate for reCaptcha human verification?**

any help on this will be helpful to me...

Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Raaj.

Answer (score 0):

You could try more usable and secure image-identification CAPTCHAs such as these - www.picatcha.com/pixcaptcha